# Is it possible to customize a text field , in iOS?

Tags: ios, text, field

i am in need to use a text field in my application but the ones provided by XCode are only 1 line long and you can only change the width but not the hight.
I was wondering if its possible to make it look more lines long?
Is it only possible with customization and if yes any good tutorials? 
Thank you!

Comment: Why not using UITextView instead? A UITextField is targeted as single line, UITextView's are targeted to be multiline

Comment: What's with the tutorials? Why not try reading the documentation?

Comment: the documentation sucks.. if theres no sample code for new programmer nothing makes sense..

Comment: Yes it is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, you can actually change the height of a `UITextField`. Just change the border style in the Attributes Inspector to anything except the default "rounded corners". You can then resize it right in Interface Builder. If you really wanted to, you could even change it back in your `viewDidLoad` method like this:

```
self.myTextField.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
```

However, to have multiple lines, you have to use a `UITextView`. It's by default multi-line, but see the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html) for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `UITextView`. The document about it [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UITextView_Class/Reference/UITextView.html). If you need something else, please post an image of what you want to achieve.